# I have following code to upload my attachment.But I couldn't upload it into my own path. How should I change following code?

Tags: upload, path, ejb-3.0, servlet-3.0, fileitem

```
      if (isMultipart) {
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        try {
            // Parse the request
            List /* FileItem */ items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();
               if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = item.getName();
                    String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                    File path = new File(root+"/uploads");
                    if (!path.exists()) {
                        boolean status = path.mkdirs();
                        System.out.println("status"+status);
                    }
                    File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
                    item.write(uploadedFile);                                         
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My attachment are stored in machine dependent location. How I change it into my own location? (ex:-war/uploads/..). Now path shows my machine name also.(ex:-/home/name/NetBeansProjects/prjname/dist/wldeploy/prjname/prjname-war.war/uploads/image.jpg)